# Issue of ASP controls displayed in table form on browser html page

Tags: html, asp.net

Local version of my asp.net web application display menu control data in html div tag and live version displays it in html table can any one tell me why this happens ?

```
 <asp:Menu ID="DynamicMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSourceCustRole"
                    BackColor="#FFFBD6" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" BorderStyle="None" Height="21px"
                    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="#990000" Orientation="Horizontal"
                    StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="4" DynamicMenuItemStyle-Font-Names="Verdana"
                    DynamicMenuItemStyle-Font-Size="0.8em" OnLoad="DynamicMenu_Load" OnMenuItemClick="OnClick"
                    CssSelectorClass="CssAdapterMenu">
                    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
                    <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" />
                    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:Menu>
```

HTML Rendered code at Local version

```
<div id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu" class="CssAdapterMenu">
            <div class="AspNet-Menu-Horizontal">
                    <ul class="AspNet-Menu">
                        <li class="AspNet-Menu-WithChildren">
                            <span class="AspNet-Menu-NonLink">
                                Administrator</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                                    <a title="Create Roles For the User" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" href="BackOffice/AdminRights/CreateRoles.aspx">
                                        Create Roles</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                                    <a title="Create Access Rules For the User" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" href="BackOffice/AdminRights/CreateAccessRules.aspx">
                                        Create Access Rules</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                                    <a title="User Status For the User" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" href="BackOffice/AdminRights/User.aspx">
                                        User Status</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="AspNet-Menu-WithChildren">
                                    <span class="AspNet-Menu-NonLink">
                                        Configuration</span>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                                            <a title="Time Zone Offset" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" href="BackOffice/Configuration/TimeOffSetMaster.aspx">
                                                Time Zone Offset</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                                            <a title="Common Setting" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" href="BackOffice/Configuration/CommonSetting.aspx">
                                                Common Setting</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                                            <a title="Company Setting" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" href="BackOffice/Configuration/CompanySetting.aspx">
                                                Company Setting</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                                            <a title="TemplateSetting" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" href="BackOffice/Configuration/TemplateSetting.aspx">
                                                TemplateSetting</a>
                                        </li>
```

HTML Rendered on live version

```
<a href="#ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_SkipLink"><img width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" src="/WebResource.axd?d=vcFBVdJkqWhUa_v0q6LDOxeV_dT8mcvk0VCkxtt-xn5qxLv-jqeFGtbO4qnM2Lc7uM4mwtankfNUJmE_t5h9PUvBOQ81&amp;t=634605430860686371" alt="Skip Navigation Links"></a><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" cssselectorclass="CssAdapterMenu" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_2" id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenun0" title="Displays the Admin Menu." onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_4">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a style="cursor:text;" href="#" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_1 ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_3">Administrator</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" alt="Expand Administrator" src="/WebResource.axd?d=gxvOxBWRzLCOGR_VNyxocwPpKqUutMKXuoE6SRjTO2mMBeQqpA5qvAWnQz3OMKLNFaUkBMCZE1qYBMBcgjY5fHgyVO01&amp;t=634605430860686371"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table></td><td id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenun1" title="Displays the Customer Master." onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_4">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a style="cursor:text;" href="#" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_1 ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_3">Masters            </a></td><td style="width:0;"><img style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" alt="Expand Masters            " src="/WebResource.axd?d=gxvOxBWRzLCOGR_VNyxocwPpKqUutMKXuoE6SRjTO2mMBeQqpA5qvAWnQz3OMKLNFaUkBMCZE1qYBMBcgjY5fHgyVO01&amp;t=634605430860686371"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table></td><td id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenun2" title="Common Masters      " onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_4">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a style="cursor:text;" href="#" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_1 ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_3">Common Masters      </a></td><td style="width:0;"><img style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" alt="Expand Common Masters      " src="/WebResource.axd?d=gxvOxBWRzLCOGR_VNyxocwPpKqUutMKXuoE6SRjTO2mMBeQqpA5qvAWnQz3OMKLNFaUkBMCZE1qYBMBcgjY5fHgyVO01&amp;t=634605430860686371"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table></td><td id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenun3" title="Displays the Operations" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_4">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a style="cursor:text;" href="#" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_1 ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_3">Operation/Report</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" alt="Expand Operation/Report" src="/WebResource.axd?d=gxvOxBWRzLCOGR_VNyxocwPpKqUutMKXuoE6SRjTO2mMBeQqpA5qvAWnQz3OMKLNFaUkBMCZE1qYBMBcgjY5fHgyVO01&amp;t=634605430860686371"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table></td><td id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenun4" title="Manage" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_4">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a style="cursor:text;" href="#" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_1 ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_3">Manage</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" alt="Expand Manage" src="/WebResource.axd?d=gxvOxBWRzLCOGR_VNyxocwPpKqUutMKXuoE6SRjTO2mMBeQqpA5qvAWnQz3OMKLNFaUkBMCZE1qYBMBcgjY5fHgyVO01&amp;t=634605430860686371"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table></td><td id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenun5" title="Booking" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_4">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a style="cursor:text;" href="#" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_1 ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_3">Bookings</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" alt="Expand Bookings" src="/WebResource.axd?d=gxvOxBWRzLCOGR_VNyxocwPpKqUutMKXuoE6SRjTO2mMBeQqpA5qvAWnQz3OMKLNFaUkBMCZE1qYBMBcgjY5fHgyVO01&amp;t=634605430860686371"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><div class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_0 ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_7" id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenun0Items" style="visibility: hidden; display: none; top: 23px; height: 67px; clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto); left: 5px; z-index: 1;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="top: 0px;">
                <tbody><tr id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenun6" title="Create Roles For the User" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)">
                    <td><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_6">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a href="BackOffice/AdminRights/CreateRoles.aspx" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_1 ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_5">Create Roles</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table></td>
                </tr><tr id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenun7" title="Create Access Rules For the User" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)">
                    <td><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_6">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a href="BackOffice/AdminRights/CreateAccessRules.aspx" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_1 ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_5">Create Access Rules</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table></td>
                </tr><tr id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenun8" title="User Status For the User" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)">
                    <td><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_6">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a href="BackOffice/AdminRights/User.aspx" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_1 ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_5">User Status</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table></td>
                </tr><tr id="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenun9" title="Configuration" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)">
                    <td><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_6">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a style="cursor:text;" href="#" class="ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_1 ctl00_Admin_Menu_DynamicMenu_5">Configuration</a></td><td style="width:0;"><img style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" alt="Expand Configuration" src="/WebResource.axd?d=gxvOxBWRzLCOGR_VNyxocwPpKqUutMKXuoE6SRjTO2mMBeQqpA5qvAWnQz3OMKLNFaUkBMCZE1qYBMBcgjY5fHgyVO01&amp;t=634605430860686371"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: please show some code of your web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local copy is running asp.net 4, your host is running 3.5.

You can force the rendering mode by setting the `RenderingMode` property. More details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.renderingmode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that IIS application pool of your website on server uses same version of .NET Framework like your development machine.